# VB.Net Combobox to display text which refers to a value

Tags: vb.net

I would like to display a number of items in a combobox and when the user selects on, instead of the text being returned a specific value referring to that text is returned.  Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please, afford a bit of your time to read FAQ. In particular [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical `Key,Value` binding. I will use a `Dictionary`, as an example. So assuming you have populated your Dictionary with proper values, the code can look like this:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = yourDictionary.ToList
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
```

You can then pick the value using `ComboBox1.SelectedValue` property.